# Split NSString and keep split character

Tags: ios, objective-c, split, nsstring

I have a string with some new line characters in it and I need to split it up. currently I'm using:

```
NSArray *a = [string componentsSeperatedByString:@"\n"];
```

However, this gets rid of all the new line characters. How can I keep those elements as part of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the string yourself.

```
NSMutableArray *lines = [NSMutableArray array];
NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(0, string.length);
while (1) {
    NSRange newlineRange = [string rangeOfString:@"\n" options:NSLiteralSearch range:searchRange];
    if (newlineRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSInteger index = newlineRange.location + newlineRange.length;
        NSString *line = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(searchRange.location, index - searchRange.location)];
        [lines addObject:line];
        searchRange = NSMakeRange(index, string.length - index);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

NSLog(@"lines = %@", lines);
```

Comment: This works. I think there's just some other formating things i need to fix other places in code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no API for doing it. A simple solution would be to build a second array starting from the components, as follows

```
NSString *separator = @".";
NSArray *components = [@"ab.c.d.ef.gh" componentsSeparatedByString:separator];
NSMutableArray *finalComponents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:components.count * 2 - 1];
[components enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id component, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    [finalComponents addObject:component];
    if (idx < components.count - 1) {
        [finalComponents addObject:separator];
    }
}];
NSLog(@"%@", finalComponents); // => ["ab", ".", "c", ".", "d", ".", "ef", ".", "gh"]
```

Not extremely efficient, but probably not a huge concern unless dealing with a very high number of components.

Comment: Well let's say you were dealing with a full word doc (several pages). Would this be an issue?

Comment: the easiest answer is: try and see. However rmaddy's solution is probably more efficient.